# Git lfs version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1 oid error

Tags: r, git, r-markdown, git-lfs

I am working on creating a simple R Markdown website hosted as a GitHub website (`xxx.github.io`). I have a few sub-pages which are also written in R and knitted to HTML, so the path to them would be in the format `xxx.github.io/subpagex.html`

However, one of my subpages when knitted to HTML exceeded 100mb and required lfs tracking. So I installed git lfs, tracked the file at (`docs/subpagex.html`), committed and pushed.

However when I try `xxx.github.io/subpagex.html` it gives me the following error `version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1 oid sha256:e4024c70f19f3dfsgsgsfgfgsfgfgsfgsfda4e537afc9fbab7037633651b08 size 140010078`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is a pointer file that's used by Git LFS to store in the repository.  When Git LFS is enabled, this file is replaced by the large file in question.  However, when it's not enabled, you see a pointer file like this one instead.

In your case, GitHub Pages doesn't support Git LFS, so that's why you're seeing the pointer file.  Your only option is to make your document smaller so it fits in the repository without Git LFS.  Note that 100 MB for any HTML file is really excessive and you cannot expect anyone to want to download that much data for a web page.

Answer (score 0):

When Git LFS is used to store in the repository then your repository supports LFS, if so then you have to use Git LFS command for cloning your projects i.e. for cloning

```
$ git lfs clone git@bitbucket.org:tpettersen/Atlasteroids.git
```

for further visit https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs#clone-respository